# How do I put multiple actors in a list and have them move - python pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pgzero

How can I move actors in a list in pygame, here's what I've tried: `

```
boxes = []
for i in range(10):
    h = random.randint(0,200)
    w = random.randint(0,200)
    boxes.append( Actor("red.png"))
def draw():

    red.draw()
for i in range(len(boxes)):
  boxes[i].center = (-570,250 -50*i)`
```

But it gives me an error like red is not defined. How do I fix this?

Comment: The question is about [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), not about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news)

Comment: Is there a difference?

Comment: Yes of course. For example, Pygame doesn't have an `Actor`. Pygame Zero is for absolute beginners.

Comment: Good to know! I'm new to it so good info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `x` and `y` attribute of the [`Actor`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#actors) object:

```py
boxes = []
for i in range(10):
    actor = Actor("red.png")
    actor.x = random.randint(0, 200)
    actor.y = random.randint(0, 200)
    boxes.append(actor)
```

If you want to move the objects, you need to change the coordinates. e.g:

```py
for box in boxes:
    box.x += 1
```

Comment: Thanks that's great!